# How to post to a facebook group wall in offline mode using graph API? (I am a member of group)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I am trying to post a status update on the wall of a group which I am a member of. Here is the code I am using

```
            <?php
            require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';    
            $appId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';    
            $appSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';    
            $extended_access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

            $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => $appId, 'secret' => $appSecret)); 

            $msg_body = array(
                'message' => 'Good evening',
                'type' => 'status',
                'access_token' => $extended_access_token,
            );

            $groups = array(
                            'Group name' => '1234567',
                        );
            foreach($groups as $group_name => $group_id){
                try {
                    $post_url = "/$id/feed";
                    $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
                    print_r($postResult);
                } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                    echo $e;
                }   
            }
            ?>
```

If I login to fb via browser and hit this page in a new tab, the message is getting posted to the group wall. But If I am not logged into facebook, then if I hit this page, no message is getting posted and I am getting an error message

```
OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

How can I post to this group via offline mode? Searched a lot for this, could not find any useful info.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the permissions from the group owner

Comment: but why its working if I am logged into FB in a tab? The message is saved in group as "posted x minutes ago via app_name"

Comment: what do you call extended access token? is it the long-live token?

Comment: anybody got any info?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$id` to `$group_id` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score -2):

you ned to get apps this permession : publish_actions,publish_stream,user_groups,